# Get search?id={id} to appear in the URL using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm creating a search feature and I'm trying to get the id to appear on the url using the search form. When I manually put in search?id=1 it gets the correct item but when using my form it doesn't seem to get the id and doesn't add it on the end of the url, not sure what I'm doing wrong but would appreciate the help thank you.

Route

```
    Route::get('/search', 'HomeController@search')->name('search');
    Route::resource('home', 'HomeController');
```

Controller

```
    public function search(Request $request){
        $post = Post::where('id', $request->id)->first();
        $posts = Post::all();

        if (Post::where('id', '=', Input::get('id'))->exists()) {
            return view('Frontend::pages.press.show', compact('post', 'posts'));
        }else if (Post::where('id', '=', 0)) {
            return view('Frontend::pages.press.press', compact('post', 'posts'));
        }
    }
```

View

```
                                    <form method="get" action="{{ route('search') ?? ''}}">
                                        <div class="md-form">
                                            <label style="font-weight: 600; display: contents;" for="form2" class="active white-text">Vehicles in stock</label>
                                            <select style="margin-top: 0.5rem;" class="form-control search-form-control white-text">
                                                <option id="0" value="volvo">Any vehicle...</option>
                                                @foreach($posts as $post)
                                                    <option id="{{$post->id}}" value="volvo">{{$post->vehicle}} {{$post->h1}}</option>
                                                @endforeach
                                            </select>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="text-center mt-4">
                                            <button style="background-color: #2d3e50!important;" class="btn btn-indigo">Search</button>
                                            <hr class="mb-3 mt-4 hr-light">
                                            <div class="inline-ul text-center">
                                                <a class="p-2 m-2 li-ic">
                                                    <i class="fab fa-linkedin-in white-text"> </i>
                                                </a>
                                                <a class="p-2 m-2 ins-ic">
                                                    <i class="fab fa-facebook-f white-text"> </i>
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<select>` element needs a `name` attribute. Also, make sure your `<option>`s have different values. Change your `<select...>` to this:

```
<select name="id" style="margin-top: 0.5rem;" class="form-control search-form-control white-text">
  <option value="0">Any vehicle...</option>
  @foreach($posts as $post)
    <option value="{{$post->id}}">{{$post->vehicle}} {{$post->h1}}</option>
  @endforeach
</select>
```

(Added a `name` attribute and used `{{$post->id}}` as value for your `<option>`s)

Comment: Thanks I see where I was going wrong didn't give the select a name and also I wasn't passing in the id as a value in the option.